# What is the maximum capacitance allowed on SMBus? Why was the VIL fixed to a maximum of 0.8V?

Tags: smbus

How to interpret the significance of DC specification in SMBus?
Why is the VIH value has been fixed to a minimum of 2.1V?

Comment: Suppose I write a specification about my bus: RBbus. I **specify** that \$V_{IL} < 0.7 V\$. Then you make a design with the RBbus I specified but you use components that are specified for \$V_{IL} < 0.9 V\$ so \$V_{IL} = 0.8 V\$ would work OK (you need that for some reason). It works fine but it violates my RBbus spec. so you cannot and should not call it RBbus. As a user of SMBus you do not need to know **why** a spec. is < 0.8 V, you only need to follow it.

Comment: I agree with you Bimpelrekkie, but I just wanted to know that If I2C was already defined and I2C specifies VIH/VIL based on VDD i.e 0.7*VDD/0.3*VDD then what made them go back to defining a fixed level for VIH/VIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read SMBus 1.1 specifications which has very vague details on the Vih,Vil dependency on Vcc.

It doesn't explain full details but given one para of explanation. I can't put this image into comment, otherwise i could have given comment itself instead of answer. This is not actual answer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!
Now it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

> *Why is the VIH value has been fixed to a minimum of 2.1V?*

It sounds like it's to make it somewhat compatible with TTL logic levels: -

[image]

But, as per what Bimpelrekkie says in his comment, (paraphrased) it is what it is.